# Latex error: font not found, characters will be left blank

Tags: windows, fonts, latex

I've got a machine where latex is installed on windows.
It does run for one user (who is on vacation right now), and now I got to use it from a different login.

Problem is, I get a log of these errors:

```
dvips: Font <FontName> not found, characters will be left blank.
```

The fonts are all there, I suspect there is a environment variable missing which tells latex where to look for them, but since the dev whose login works is on vacation I can't check the working account for this.

Does anyone know which environment variable to set? Or what else to do to fix this problem?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there are any environment variables controlling your problem.  First place to look is [texconfig](http://man.he.net/man1/texconfig).  Run `texconfig conf` and see if you turn up any obvious problems.

Also, by any chance are you trying to use post script fonts?  If so, make sure your dvips can find the [psfonts.map](http://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/dvips.html#psfonts_002emap) file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows:

- Reinstall GhostScript
- Go to Build > Define output profiles
- Postprocessor
- Change the order to have Ghostscript (ps2pdf) at the last position.

Build your project and enjoy.

You can also:

- Reinstall GhostScript
- Go to Build > Define output profiles
- Postprocessor
- Put "DviPS" at the top
- Click on "DviPS"
- Change the path of the executable to the new GhostScript Directory (just installed at step 1)